ZDesigner GK420d printing PDF labels and the barcodes are not clear
I'm in a Windows environment using a ZDesigner GK420d (Zebra Designer) printer for shipping labels.  I am using the latest driver - v 5.1.14.7414
We have the shipping labels in pdf - when I open them, the bar codes are clear.  However, when I print via the ZDesigner GK420d they appear fuzzy with small jagged edges appearing.  How do I correct this?  I have tired amending the below settings to no avail:
Dithering
from Smooth to None

Printer settings:
Printer Fonts
from Printer default to Vector fonts

Spool format:
Printer Default to Enhanced

Speed - from 12.7 to 5

dithering none and speed 5

speed - 7.6 was 12.7
darkness - 18 was 15
What else can I try?

Create a (template) label in ZPL. This will print sharp. These printers are not designed for printing PDFs.

For whatever reason, mine will print like yours is unless I use Adobe Acrobat. I print my PDF labels from Acrobat, and it works well then.

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
